# Using WPF SplashScreen in .NET 3.5 Windows Forms

Tags: wpf, winforms, visual-studio-2008

Can I use the built in WPF splash screen functionality in a Windows Forms project compiled under .NET 3.5 SP1 Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can, but it's kinda fragile and not very straightforward.

The SplashScreen class looks for an AssemblyName + ".g" resource file. To create it, you need to include a "g.resx" file in your project. The root namespace as set in project properties must be the same as the assembly name.

This resource file needs to contain the image as a MemoryStream, NOT a System.Drawing.Bitmap! Perhaps there's an easier way, but I just included the file and then manually changed the entry to look like this:

```
<data name="splash.png" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
  <value>Splash.png;System.IO.MemoryStream, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
</data>
```

Then just include the following lines in your Main method:

```
var splash = new SplashScreen("Splash.png");
splash.Show(true);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

jachymko's answer is correct, but a bit underspecified.

First, add a reference to WindowsBase. The specific code is

```
var splash = new System.Windows.SplashScreen("guru_logo.png");
splash.Show(true);
```

In order for this to work your g.resx file must be at the project level, not in the Properties folder. If your resx was by default in Properties (like mine) you need to drag it up to the project level.

This is what the relevant section of my g.resx looked like

```
 <data name="guru_logo.png" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>Resources\guru_logo.png;System.IO.MemoryStream, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</value>
  </data>
```

Notice that the SplashScreen is calling the data name, not the value. Also note the path represented in the value.

If for some reason this isn't working for you (exception can't find the resource) then take a look at the code behind g.Designer.cs. The namespace there should be your assembly name. If it isn't, you need to move it to the correct position and/or change your project properties as jachymko states. Any changes you make to this file's code will be lost b/c it is autogenerated.

Answer (score 1):

I did this from a simple command-line program, compiled in a makefile.  To summarize:

- add a g.resx file
- the content must cite the graphic image you want to use for the splash screen. It can be any image type
- you must compile the .resx file using resgen.exe
- include the .resource file on the command line for csc.exe, using the /res option

in more detail...

1. the .resx file looks like this:

---

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <root>
   <xsd:schema id="root" xmlns="" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" />
    <xsd:element name="root" msdata:IsDataSet="true">
      <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xsd:element name="data">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
                <xsd:element name="comment" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="2" />
              </xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
              <xsd:attribute name="type" type="xsd:string" msdata:Ordinal="3" />
              <xsd:attribute name="mimetype" type="xsd:string" msdata:Ordinal="4" />
              <xsd:attribute ref="xml:space" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="resheader">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
              </xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
        </xsd:choice>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
  </xsd:schema>
  <resheader name="resmimetype">
    <value>text/microsoft-resx</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="version">
    <value>2.0</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="reader">
    <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceReader, System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="writer">
    <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter, System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
  </resheader>
  <data name="hourglass.jpg" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>hourglass.jpg;System.IO.MemoryStream, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
</data>
</root>
```

1. Compile with resgen.exe, which is included with the Windows SDK.  For example:

---

```
c:\winsdk\bin\resgen.exe  g.resx g.resources
```

---

1. Specify the resulting .resources on the csc.exe command line.  For example:

---

```
csc.exe /t:exe /debug+ /win32icon:MyApp.ico /res:g.resources,MyApp.g.resources /R:... ...
```